# CasperJS test with PhantomJS webserver fails to load local image

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have a CasperJS test suite that needs to verify an image onload event. To test this I have a 1x1 pixel gif image, which I serve using PhantomJS webserver:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var webserver = require('webserver');

casper.test.begin('Image onload should be invoked', 1, {
    setUp: function() {
        var server = webserver.create();
        this.server = server.listen(8080, function(request, response) {
            if (request.url == '/') {
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

                response.write('' +
                    '<!doctype html>\n' +
                    '<html>\n' +
                        '<head>\n' +
                            '<script type="text/javascript">\n' +
                                'window.onload = function() {\n' +
                                    'var px = document.createElement("img");\n' +
                                    'px.onload = function() {\n' +
                                        'window._pxLoad = true;\n' +
                                    '};\n' +
                                    'px.src = "px.gif";\n' +
                                '};\n' +
                            '</script>\n' +
                        '</head>\n' +
                        '<body></body>\n' +
                    '</html>' +
                '');
            } else if (request.url.match(/px\.gif$/i)) {
                response.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'image/gif',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
                });

                var filePath = fs.workingDirectory + request.url.split('/').join(fs.separator).replace(/\d/gi, '');

                response.write(fs.read(filePath));
            }

            response.close();
        });
    },

    tearDown: function() {
        this.server.close();
    },

    test: function(test) {
        casper.start('http://localhost:8080', function() {
            this.waitFor(function() {
                return this.evaluate(function () {
                    return window._pxLoad !== undefined;
                });
            }, function then() {
                var flag = this.evaluate(function () {
                    return window._pxLoad;
                });

                test.assertTruthy(flag, 'Image has been successfully loaded');
            });
        });

        casper.run(function () {
            test.done();
        });
    }
});
```

This test fails because `window._pxLoad !== undefined` did not evaluate within the 5000ms timeout. I even placed `console.log` statements inside image handler and they showed that my routing works, server do receive this `/px.gif` call, but looks like git image isn't served at all.
I tried to replace the call to local `px.gif` with the similar image from the Internet, [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif), and test passed! So the problem is definitely relates to how local gif image is served by PhantomJS webserver.

Comment: Yes, I know about casper's `resourceExists`, `waitForResource` and others. I have a really specific test case to cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like I've found an answer by myself. Well, sort of.
First of all, I couldn't make my PhantomJS webserver solution work. So I created a simple Node.js script which runs a webserver. It is spawned as a child process before running test suite:

**img_server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var argv = process.argv;
var port = argv.length > 3 ? parseInt(argv[3], 10) || 8124;

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'px.gif'));

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'image/gif',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    });

    fileStream.pipe(res);
}).listen(port);

// This is important. Script should put something in the STDOUT when started.
// The CasperJS test suite will bind to this inside setUp hook to know when server is ready
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
```

Changes to CasperJS test suite:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var webserver = require('webserver');
var process = require('child_process');
var spawn = process.spawn;

casper.test.setUp(function(done) {
    this.imgServerChild = spawn('node', ['img_server.js', '-p', '8180']);
    // This where STDOUT from server script is used
    this.imgServerChild.stdout.on("data", done);
});
casper.test.tearDown(function() {
    this.imgServerChild.kill('SIGKILL');
});

// The rest of test suite
```

Of course I also changed the path to the image file inside the faked HTML output. Now image is served from different domain, which is totally fine for me. Now tests are working.